# How to use app.locals variables outside of middleware/router

Tags: node.js, express

I get undefined when I use the app.locals. I am just using app.local as config variable. how do I use it inside the listen(PORT)

app.js

```
app.locals = {
    socket_io_host: 'http://localhost:3001',
    socket_io_port: "3001",
};
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var server = require('http').Server(express).listen(app.locals.socket_io_port);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

console.log("["+app.locals.socket_io_port+"]");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express',point1: point1,point2: point2 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to require it:

app.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  socket_io_host: 'http://localhost:3001',
  socket_io_port: "3001",
}
```

index.js:

```js
// put as the first line
var app = require('./app');
```